# Grab City Name from an Address via Regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

[image]

How can i grab the city name from an address. The city come just before the Province/State. In the given snapshot, the city would be Collingwood Town. The city name will always precedes the last comma. Lets take another example,

> 100 James St. Bldn #5, 
> Floor 5, P.O Box 555 
> XCity, XProvice

I need a regex that fetches XCity and dumps it into a variable. Also, it takes whatever before the XCity and dumps into another variable, i.e.,

address = 100 James St.
Bldn #5, Floor 5, P.O Box 555

city = XCity

What splits address and city is either a comma or a newline.

Can anyone help me achieving it in Ruby? The whole text reside in a string variable.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think so this could work:

```
split = address.split(',')
city = split[split.length-2] if split.length >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using regex:

```
r = /.*\s(?<city>[a-zA-Z]*),\s(?<prov>[a-zA-Z]*)/.match("100 James St. Bldn #5, Floor 5, P.O Box 555 XCity, XProvince")

puts "City: #{r['city']}"
puts "Province: #{r['prov']}"
```

Answer (score 0):

**In ruby, you can use "match" function:**

s="100 James St. Bldn #5,
Floor 5, P.O Box 555
XCity, XProvice"
puts s

puts s.match('[A-Z][a-z]*, ')

this will return: **City,**